# Sanitizing GET input with PHP. Is it too late and do I even need to?

Tags: php, get, httprequest

I am trying to sanitize the user input in a search through an array. I am wondering if I am sanitizing the input in the right way and if I even need it in a function like this. You'll get it:

Main questions #1: Am I "sanitizing" the input the right way at the right place or is it too late.

The HTML ->

```
<div >
    <form class="theform"> 
    Jeg vil gerne have: <input class="theinputbox" type="text" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)">
    </form>
</div>
<div id="theHint"><span id="txtHint"></span></div>
```

The javascript with showHint(); ->

```
function showHint(str) {

    if (str.length === 0) { 
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "ToostGetHint.php?q=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

The PHP with the array and result ->

```
    <?php
    $a[] = "Anna";
    $a[] = "Brittany";
    $a[] = "Cinderella";

    $q = test_input($_REQUEST["q"]);

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}


    $hint = "";

    // lookup all hints from array if $q is different from "" 
    if ($q !== "") {
        $q = strtolower($q);
        $len=strlen($q);
        foreach($a as $name) {
            if (stristr($q, substr($name, 0, $len))) {
                if ($hint === "") {
                    $hint =  '<p class="txtHint">' . $name . '</p>';
                } else {
                    $hint .= '<p class="txtHint">' . $name . '</p>';
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Output "no suggestion" if no hint was found or output correct values 
    echo $hint === "" ? "no suggestion" : $hint;
    ?>
```

Comment: why are you doing this `echo $hint === "" ? "no suggestion" : $hint;` i mean assigning??

Comment: "txtHint" is an id or a class?or both?

Comment: That is not assigning? There is a comment on it. But I will try to explain anyway, like this: echo checks if ($hint === "") is true, it is it it will echo "no suggestion, "else" if it is not empty it will echo $hint.

Comment: @Lambda7 "txthint" is an id.

Comment: Then you should correct it in $hint =  '<p class="txtHint">' . $name . '</p>'; and the second one

Comment: I have txtHint as a class and an id :s hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your specific case, you do not need to sanitize. You never output the input so there is no chance of XSS, and you never use the input in a SQL statement so there is no chance of SQL injection.

If you wanted to sanitize, for this specific case, you should whitelist the characters that you wish to allow. Since you are matching names, you really only need to allow upper and lower case letters. You can implement a white list through the use of a regex.